# What is the best way to get the unique records from a table with less impact on performance?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

What is the best way to get the unique records from a table with less impact on performance? These are the set of column combination which is causing the duplicate issue.

```
SELECT
  PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY,
  AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY,
  AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY,
  SCHEDULE_LINE_ID,
  SRC_CREATED_DATE,
  SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE
FROM
  EDWFIN.PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_ROLLUP_FRS_356
GROUP BY
  PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY,
  AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY,
  AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY,
  SCHEDULE_LINE_ID,
  SRC_CREATED_DATE,
  SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE
```

Comment: What is wrong with your method?

Comment: Actually, this query will be used in the merge statement with another table with the help of the Using clause, so using count(*) =1 causes lots of performance stress are we are already merging it with 118Million records table .. hence wanted to take only unique records to reduce the burdon..

Comment: Did you have a reason to use `group by` rather than `distinct` - e.g have you already tested both and found your approach to be more performant? Are there other methods you've tested and ruled out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to check which query is more performant, but you can also use:

```sql
SELECT PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY,
       AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY,
       AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY,
       SCHEDULE_LINE_ID,
       SRC_CREATED_DATE,
       SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE
FROM   (
  SELECT PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY,
         AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY,
         AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY,
         SCHEDULE_LINE_ID,
         SRC_CREATED_DATE,
         SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY PAY_RANGE_START_DATE_KEY,
                        AA_PERSON_NATURAL_KEY,
                        AA_PERSON_ASSIGNMENT_KEY,
                        SCHEDULE_LINE_ID,
                        SRC_CREATED_DATE,
                        SRC_LAST_UPDATE_DATE
           ORDER BY ROWNUM
        ) AS rn
  FROM  EDWFIN.PSP_LABOR_SCHD_DAY_F_ROLLUP_FRS_356
)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: @MTO thanks for the input, Is there an alternative method too? so that i can check the performance of both and comapre

Comment: @karthik Yes, the one you posted in the question.

Comment: @MTO ok thank you so much for the timely help, Are there any more methods to get the unique records from a table in oracle?